# In Material UI how can I dynamically pass down the color to my style?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

New to React and Material UI I'm stumped how to properly pass down a color dynamically I'm pulling from a JSON file and I'm not finding a good reference in my searches, StackOverflow or in the docs.

### Research

- [Material-ui hoverColor for MenuItem component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839297/material-ui-hovercolor-for-menuitem-component)
- [How can I access a hover state in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125708/how-can-i-access-a-hover-state-in-reactjs)
- [How do I change Material-UI MenuItem background on hover change from AutoComplete props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536092/how-do-i-change-material-ui-menuitem-background-on-hover-change-from-autocomplet)
- [Material UI inline styling - specific component colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52794248/material-ui-inline-styling-specific-component-colours)

### Attempt

Given the JSON file:

```json
[
  {
    "label": "Home",
    "href": "/",
    "colorHover": ""
  },
  {
    "label": "Monday",
    "href": "/mon",
    "colorHover": "#35c5bd"
  },
  {
    "label": "Tuesday",
    "href": "/tues",
    "colorHover": "#fa8b25"
  },
  {
    "label": "Wednesday",
    "href": "/wed",
    "colorHover": "#f26531"
  }
]
```

I bring it into my component and loop through it with:

```js
  const getDrawerChoices = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href, colorHover }) => {
      const colorChange = colorHover === '' ? 'inherit' : colorHover

      return (
        <Link
          {...{
            component: RouterLink,
            to: href,
            color: 'inherit',
            style: { textDecoration: 'none' },
            key: label,
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem className={menuItem.hover(colorChange)}>{label}</MenuItem>
        </Link>
      )
    })
  }
```

Material UI Styles:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(colorChange => ({
  menuItem: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: `${colorChange} !important`,
    },
  },
}))
```

but I'm thrown an error. How can I pass a color value dynamically to useStyles or do I need to do it inline with the ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a custom `makeStyle` passing a prop to every key as follows:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: (props) => ({
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: props.hoverColor
    }
  })
});
```

I'll leave a [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-violet-p8y6o?file=/src/App.js:145-269) with what I tested and the [link](https://material-ui.com/es/styles/basics/#adapting-based-on-props) to the docs. Anything else I can do let me know.

Comment: Ya for some reason I'm still getting an error: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-shannon-52p3l?file=/src/components/Header.js

Comment: Right, you cannot use hooks inside callbacks. I've updated the solution on the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-violet-p8y6o?file=/src/App.js), my recommendation is to split the component in order to be able to use the hook and get the custom styles for each component.

Comment: ah I see now. The docs arent very clear in this area .